# How would I apply a rather complex summation formula like this in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, iteration

This is the data table I am working with.

[image]

This is the formula I need to apply in Excel.

[image]

I want to clarify some notations. `k_p_x` means the probability that the individual aged `x` will survive for the next `k` years.

`p_x` would simply assume `k=1`. And is the probability of surviving for the next 1 year. And obviously `k_p_x` can be computed using these single year probabilities.

In my datatable in Excel I have all of the single year probability of survival.

However, in my formula I need to add multiple iterations of `k_p_x` which makes this a little complicated.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this in Excel?
Or should I use Rstudio instead?

I tried playing around with `SUM()` with `PRODUCT()` inside. But I am not sure how to reiterate `k_p_x` for k=1,2,3... up to like 100.

Comment: Create a new column for kpx.

Comment: So what iterations do you need? What's the formula you use without iterating?